# Android: Importing library removes R. folder

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock, android-support-library, r.java-file

I have a strange issue. I have working application project (working with appcompat-support-lib) and i want to add there [ActionBarSherlock-library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock). After I add this lib to my project, after a while it removes my R.java folder - so i get errors in almost every class of my project.

Do you know how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've solved it this way:

- I've created new project and added support library `ActionBarSherlock`
- A copied all of previous project to current - using Sherlock
- I put the same package to second project
- And of course I had to change some things in classes (`Fragment` to `SherlockFragment` etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding `ActionBarSherlock` to your project when you've already got your project working with the appcompat library? They both use attributes and resources, that are named the same, so this causes issues. You can't use both at the same time.

Comment: i need to change it, because only sherlock supports searchview on API 7 and lower

Comment: Then remove appcompat and add ABS afterwards.

Comment: Im trying that and the remove actually removes the R folder too and if i add another, it doesnt put it back

Comment: Resolve all the errors, that are generated by removing ABC. Everything will be error-free after you've successfully migrated from ABS to ABS.

Comment: Error I always get is: Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies

Comment: Make sure that ABS uses the same version of the support library like your application

Comment: Yes it uses. I have checked. Now I also tried to create new project and add there ABS and it works well. Only replacing libs doesnt work

Comment: Does it still say "Jar mismatch"?

Comment: Yes it does. I also tried to replace v4 lib in sherlock with that in the appcompat. It still says the same statement